# How to set maximum time to connect for rsync?

Tags: rsync

I'd like to be able to set a timeout for my rsync commands to connect to the target node.

(Not a maximum time that rsync can be connected, just the maximum amount of time it will wait for the server to respond).

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

The man page contains this here:

**--timeout=TIMEOUT**
*This option allows you to set a maximum IO timeout in seconds. If no data is transferred for the specified time then rsync will exit. The default is 0, which means no timeout.*